# Unexpected token in button listener

Tags: java, android

I've made a button listener for my app, but it says that an else is an unexpected token but I don't know why. This is my code and the else with ?????? behind it is the unexpected token, I hope someone can help me:

```
//Start of Button Listener for Button1
    mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //My logic for Button goes in here

        if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswerFrankrijk)

            mScoreFrankrijk++;
            updateScore(mScoreFrankrijk);

            //perform check before you update the question
            if (mQuestionNumber == QuestionLibrary.mQuestionsFrankrijk.length) {
                Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, QuizResultaat.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("finalScore", mScoreFrankrijk);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                QuizActivityFrankrijk.this.finish();
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
        else {
            if (mQuestionNumber == QuestionLibrary.mQuestionsFrankrijk.length) {
                Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, QuizResultaat.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("finalScore", mScoreFrankrijk);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                QuizActivityFrankrijk.this.finish();
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                updateQuestion();
            }
        }
    });

 //End of Button Listener for Button1
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a starting `{` in your first `if` statement

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a { at this line

```
if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswerFrankrijk)
```